# Сортировать словарь по значению

Tags: python-3.x

Подскажите, как  отсортировать список словарей `l1`  по значению ключа `age` без использования дополнительных модулей?

```
l1 = [{'name': '1', 'age': '29'}, {'name': '2', 'age': '31'}, {'name': '3', 'age': '32'},{'name': '4', 'age': '31'}, {'name': '4', 'age': '32'}]
```

Comment: В вашем вопросе нет ни слова от том что нельзя использовать встроенные функции. Так как вам уже дали ответы на данный вопрос я бы вам посоветовал открыть новый вопрос, внятно описать задачу и привести в вопросе ваши попытки решения задачи...

Comment: ["Как задать хороший вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

встроенная функция [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) возвращает отстортированный аргумент, но не изменяет сам аргумент.

```
In [157]: sorted(l1, key=lambda x: int(x['age']))
Out[157]:
[{'name': '1', 'age': '29'},
 {'name': '2', 'age': '31'},
 {'name': '4', 'age': '31'},
 {'name': '3', 'age': '32'},
 {'name': '4', 'age': '32'}]
```

PS для правильной сортировки надо использовать `int(x['age'])` иначе получим лексикографическую сортировку, где `'9'` больше `'19'`

---

**UPDATE:** реализация наивного алгоритма сортировки пузырьком:

```
def bbl_sort(arr, key=lambda x: x):
    arr = arr.copy()
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(0, n-i-1):
            if key(arr[j]) > key(arr[j+1]):
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]
    return arr

res = bbl_sort(l1, key=lambda x: int(x['age']))
```

исходный словарь:

```
In [171]: l1
Out[171]:
[{'name': '1', 'age': '29'},
 {'name': '2', 'age': '31'},
 {'name': '3', 'age': '19'},
 {'name': '4', 'age': '31'},
 {'name': '5', 'age': '32'}]
```

результат сортировки:

```
In [172]: res
Out[172]:
[{'name': '3', 'age': '19'},
 {'name': '1', 'age': '29'},
 {'name': '2', 'age': '31'},
 {'name': '4', 'age': '31'},
 {'name': '5', 'age': '32'}]
```

Comment: Спасибо. А если использовать такие функции нельзя?Я пытался вывести отдельно возраст а потом через метод "пузырька"б сортироватьб но запутался ...

Comment: Тогда реализуйте любой известный вам алгоритм сортировки

Comment: Та я понимаю, пытался отдельно вывести "ages", а потом через метод пузырька" отсортировать но....ничего не вышло....
Я понял.Спасибо

Comment: ages = [x['age'] for x in l1]

for ages1 in range(0, len(ages) - 1):
    for ages2 in range(0, len(ages) -ages1- 1):
        if int(ages[ages2]) < int(ages[ages2+1]):
           l1[ages2], l1[ages2 + 1] = l1[ages2 + 1], l1[ages2]

print(l1)
но результат не выерный.... я видимо полный и..от...

Comment: @Валерий, в моем ответе готовая и рабочая реализация пузырьковой сортировки...

Comment: Я понимаю, я вижу, Вы определяете функцию. Но я еще профан, мягко говоря, я пытаюсь просто по имеющимся данным , написать выражения и вывести результат. С Python, я ровно две недели работаю, и очень путаюсь, извините. Можно просто переписать это без функции?

Comment: @Валерий, можно, просто перепишите без функции... ;-)

Comment: n = len(list_dict1)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(0, n-i-1):
     if key(list_dict1[j]) > key(list_dict1[j+1]):
            list_dict1[j], list_dict1[j+1] = list_dict1[j+1], list_dict1[j]
print(list_dict1) 
key-это что...я уже ничего не соображаю....

Comment: @Валерий, `key` - это функция доступа к атрибуту, по которому производится сортировка

Comment: Cпасибо.Я понял...без этой функции никак?задача стоит без этого всего...

Comment: @Валерий, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и/или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814)

Answer (score 0):

Самый просто способ - это использовать функцию sorted:

```
>>> l2 = sorted(l1, key=lambda x: int(x['age']))
>>> l2
[{'name': '1', 'age': '29'}, {'name': '2', 'age': '31'}, {'name': '4', 'age': '31'}, {'name': '3', 'age': '32'}, {'name': '4', 'age': '32'}]
```

Для того, чтобы отсортировать по ключу словаря - надо в качестве параметра key передать лямбда-функцию, которая будет использовать для сравнения поле `age`.

Comment: ages = [x['age'] for x in l1]

for ages1 in range(0, len(ages) - 1):
    for ages2 in range(0, len(ages) -ages1- 1):
        if int(ages[ages2]) < int(ages[ages2+1]):
           l1[ages2], l1[ages2 + 1] = l1[ages2 + 1], l1[ages2]

print(list_dict1)
но результат не выерный....

Comment: а чем плох родной метод sort()?
l1.sort( key=lambda x: int(x['age']) )

Comment: Ничем. Просто они используются в разных случаях. sorted не меняет текущий массив, а `sort` - меняет. `sorted` чуть более универсальный, потому что сортирует всё и как вы захотите. `sort` - это метод класса, который привязан к типу. И если вам надо отсортировать вам собственный класс, вам надо реализовать свой метод `sort` или использовать `sorted`.