# Сортировка словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, словари

Есть список словарей

```
list_dict1 = [{'name': 'Valera', 'age': 29}, {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 24}, {'name': 'Boris', 'age': 19}, {'name': 'Natasha', 'age': 27}, {'name': 'Kate', 'age': 32}]
```

Задача состоит в следущем:
Необходимо, отсортировать список по значению ключа'age', без использования встроеных функции
я пытался делать через метод "пузырька" следующим образом:

```
ages = [(x['age']) for x in list_dict1]
for num1 in range(0, len(ages)):
    for num2 in range(0, len(ages)-num1-1):
        if int(ages[num2]) > int(ages[num2+1]):
            list_dict1[num2], list_dict1[num2+1] = list_dict1[num2+1], list_dict1[num2]
print(list_dict1)
```

результат же не верный:

```
[{'age': 24, 'name': 'Bob'}, {'age': 29, 'name': 'Valera'}, {'age': 19, 'name': 'Boris'}, {'age': 27, 'name': 'Natasha'}, {'age': 32, 'name': 'Kate'}]
```

подскажите в чем моя ошибка, буду признателен за любую помощь.Спасибо. С уважением, В.С.В.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = len(list_dict1)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n-i-1):
        if int(list_dict1[j]['age']) > int(list_dict1[j+1]['age']):
            list_dict1[j], list_dict1[j+1] = list_dict1[j+1], list_dict1[j]

print(list_dict1)
```

но правильнее будет [оформить это в виде функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/889486/211923)

Comment: Огромнейшое спасибо!Прошу прощения за не компетентность.Я видимо не понял как обращатся к элементам словаря.

Comment: @Валерий, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и/или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).